# Face detection (viola-jones) in matlab

Tags: matlab, face-detection, matlab-cvst, viola-jones

So I found the cascade object detector in matlab that use the Viola-Jones algorithm to detect faces. Very easy to use, and works great!

But got a few questions.

The viola-jones method got four stages:

1. Haar Feature Selection
2. Creating an Integral Image
3. Adaboost Training
4. Cascading Classifiers

In matlab I can use FrontalFace(CART) and FrontalFace(LBP). These are Trained cascade classification model, so they will be part of stage 4 right?
But what is the difference between stage 1 and stage 4 if I use FrontalFace(CART)? Both use Haaar features it says.

Can we say that FrontalFace(CART) and FrontalFace(LBP) are two different ways of detecting faces? Can I compare those two against each other to see which one is better?
Or should I find another method to compare against the viola-jones?

Are there other face detection methods that are easy to implement in matlab?
Found some on the internet (using skin color etc), but Matlab is quite new to me. So I felt that those codes where abit to complicated for me.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that FrontalFace(CART) and FrontalFace(LBP) have been trained on different data sets. Also, from the name, I am guessing that FrontalFace(LBP) uses LBP feaures instead of Haar.

The original Viola-Jones algorithm used the Haar features. However, it has later been extended to use other types of features. `vision.CascadeObjectDetector` supports Haar, LBP, and HOG features.

To compare which one is better, you would need some ground truth images, which are images with faces labeled by hand. I am sure you can find a benchmark data set on the web. Alternatively, you can label you own images using `trainingImageLabeler` app.

Also, if you are not happy with the accuracy of the classifiers that come with `vision.CascadeObjectDetctor`, you can train your own using the `trainCascadeObjectDetector` function.